# В заданный массив чисел вставить другой массив, начиная с выбранной позиции

Tags: ассемблер

Задание звучит так:

> В заданный массив чисел вставить другой массив, начиная с выбранной позиции.

При проверке регистров записывается мусор или непонятные значения, гляньте в своем дебаггере плиз

```
.486
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none   

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\macros\macros.asm
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

.data

mas1 dd 1,2,3,4,5,6 ; инициализация 1 массива
mas2 dd 7,8; инициализация 2 массива

.code

start:

mov EDI, 0 ; обнуление регистров
mov ECX, 0
mov ESI, 0


mov EBP,0  ; 0-ой элемент массива mas2
mov EDI,1  ; выборка с какого элемента массива будет начало замены 





mov ECX, 2; счетчик, с которого будет при каждом повторении цикла отниматься 1

metka:
 mov ESI,mas2[EBP] ; записываю 0 елемент массива в регистр ESI
 mov mas1[EDI], ESI  ; записываю из регистра ESI значение в елемент массива mas1 на 1 позицию
 inc EBP ; переключение на след елемент массива mas2
 inc EDI; переключение на след елемент массива mas1
 loop metka

mov ECX, mas1[0] ; проверка значений массива, записываю в отдельный регистр, чтоб глянуть.
mov EBX, mas1[1];  и тоже самое..
mov EAX, mas1[2]
mov EDX, mas1[3]
;mov ECX, mas1[4]
;mov ECX, mas1[5]




int 20h
end start
```

Comment: У вас длина элемента массива (dd) занимает 4 байта. А вы к смещениям добавляете только 1. Хотя я не понимаю как masm воспринимает всякие mas1[2] может он сам на 4 умножает... Предлагаю без всяких преобразований для начала просто загрузить в регистр mas1[2] например и убедится что число правильное. Лично я бы шел более обычным для asm путем, загрузил бы скажем в edi адрес начала массива и делал бы `mov eax,[edi]` а потом добавлял бы к edi по 4. Хотя конечно современный masm вполне может что делать и за вас ...

Comment: @Mike, masm понимает как `[mas1 + 2]` (адрес начала массива + 2 байта). Т.е. никакой арифметики указателей там и в помине нет.